# Oracle JVM 8: when Codecache flushing is enabled, how much is flushed?

Tags: java, jvm

I am running an Oracle Java 8 JVM (server, not client or embedded) with ReservedCodeCacheSize=128M and UseCodeCacheFlushing enabled.  After a couple of days, the Codecache made a quick drop from 93% full to 80% full.  I assume I witnessed a Codecache flush, but it was surprising that the post-flush size was closer to 100% full than 50% full.

How does the JVM decide how much of the Codecache to flush?

[This Oracle Java 8 page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html) describes the option but does not quantify the flushed Codecache:

> Enables flushing of the code cache before shutting down the compiler. This option is enabled by default. To disable flushing of the code cache before shutting down the compiler, specify -XX:-UseCodeCacheFlushing.

[This Oracle blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/entry/why_do_i_get_message) says,

> There is a JVM option UseCodeCacheFlushing that can be used to control the flushing of the Codecache. With this option enabled JVM invokes an emergency flushing that **discards older half of the compiled code(nmethods)** to make space available in the CodeCache.

It is conceivable that the older half of the compiled code was only 20% of the overall Codecache, but another possible explanation is that the above blog post is inaccurate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*'Older half'* does not literally mean 50% of all nmethods. HotSpot logic for sweeping compiled code is a bit complicated; the best explanation is its [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/f22b5be95347/src/share/vm/runtime/sweeper.cpp), but I'll give a short summary below.

The sweeper is invoked if at least one of the following conditions is met:

1. The code cache is getting full.
2. There are enough state changes since the last sweep (JDK 8 measures *'enough'* as more than 1% of `ReservedCodeCacheSize`).
3. The certain interval has passed since the last sweep. The more space is available in Code Cache, the less frequently the sweeper is invoked. The exact formula is [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/f22b5be95347/src/share/vm/runtime/sweeper.cpp#l248).

When the sweeper runs, it always frees all *zombie* nmethods, i.e. unloaded, deoptimized or recompiled methods that have no activations.

In addition, if `UseCodeCacheFlushing` is enabled, it frees *alive* nmethods that are *cold* enough. Cold methods are determined as follows:

- At each safepoint the *hotness counter* of nmethods that have active stack frames is reset to the default value. The default hotness value is `2 * (ReservedCodeCacheSize / 1MB)`.
- Every time the sweeper runs it decreses the hotness counter of alive methods by 1.
- If the hotness counter becomes less than a computed threshold, the nmethod is freed. The threshold depends on the Code Cache free ratio and `-XX:NmethodSweepActivity` option (10 by default). The larger is `NmethodSweepActivity` and the smaller is Code Cache free ratio, the more agressively the compiled methods are sweeped. [Here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/f22b5be95347/src/share/vm/runtime/sweeper.cpp#l588) is the formula.

So, there is no exact number how many compiled methods are sweeped. This is computed in run-time, depending on the reserved Code Cache size, the amount of free space, the number of zombie methods, the number of cold methods and the JIT ergonomics options like `NmethodSweepActivity`.

Comment: You referred to the OpenJDK source.  Do you believe the Oracle JVM uses the same algorithm?

Comment: @user100464 Yes, both OpenJDK and Oracle JDK run the same HotSpot JVM, except that OpenJDK version of JVM lacks certain commercial features.